# Define a unique linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question in the textbook is the following: "Given the results of a linear map, is this linear map unique? If so, give the function rule".

I'm given $L_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Also the following results are given: $L_1(1, 2) = (0, -1)$ and $L_1(-1, 1) = (2, 1)$.

I have no idea how to even start the question. To find the correct function rule, I suppose I'll have to solve some kind of system of equations, but I'm not sure on how to start.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995642/determine-if-theres-a-linear-map-such-that)

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

In general, for a map $L:V\to W$, in order to know $L$, you need to know $L(v)$ for every single element $v$ in $V$.

But if $L$ is a linear map where $V$ is a vector space, then it suffices to know $L(v)$ for some special elements, i.e., on a **basis** of $V$. Once $L$ is known on a basis, it is *uniquely* determined.

Once $L(v)$ for every element $v$ in a basis, then it is *uniquely* determined.

So for your question, it suffices to see whether $(1,2)$ and $(-1,1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$L_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$L_1(1,2)=(0,-1)$ means that $(a+2 b,c+2 d)=(0,-1)$

$L_1(-1,1)=(2,1)\to (b-a,d-c)=(2,1)$

So we have the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
a+2b=0\\
c+2d=-1\\
b-a=2\\
d-c=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
which gives
$$a= -\frac{4}{3},b= \frac{2}{3},c= -1,d= 0$$
and finally
$$L_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{4}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$